# Greater than('>') VS greater or equal to('>=')

Tags: c

Every time I see people using >= , this question comes to my mind...

Isn't this:

> if(x>=15) {}

Slower than this?:

> if(x>14) {}

If I were to say(according to my limited knowledge of programming), the former would take 2 CPU cycles in comparison to the latter which would take just 1...

Is it slower, or do compilers optimise these little details? Or perhaps does >= take just 1 CPU cycle?

Comment: x>=15 is not the same as x>16.:)

Comment: oops mistake...

Comment: Such issues are architecture and compiler specific.  We cannot help you.